# Change from array of specified size to dynamic array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a program that's looking for certain values in a log file and listing them out. Essentially, one line of a 50000 line file would look like this:

```
Step Elapsed Temp Press Volume TotEng KinEng PotEng E_mol E_pair Pxx Pyy Pzz Pxz Pxy Pyz 
   0        0          298   -93.542117    448382.78   -67392.894     17986.81   -85379.704    12349.955   -97729.659   -313.09273    44.936408    -12.47003    100.97953    -215.4029    254.07517 
  10       10    301.05619   -14.956923    448382.78   -66191.142    18171.277   -84362.419    12474.283   -96836.702   -56.794471    103.79453   -91.870824    300.09707   -27.638439     196.2738
```

The bit of code that's doing the searching and appending looks like this:

```
line=fp.readline()

while line:
    line=fp.readline()
    words = line.split()
    if (words[0]=="Step"):
        break

numcol = len(words)
header = words

data = numpy.zeros((numcol,100000))

ln = 0

while line:
    line=fp.readline()
    words=line.split()
    if(words[0]=="Loop"):
        break

    for i in range(numcol):
        data[i][ln]=(float(words[i]))

    ln_original = ln
    ln = ln +1
```

Currently, I'm specifying the number of columns in my array. I can't seem to figure out how to get appending to work. Any ideas as to what I could change so that the array can be dynamic for log files of various lengths instead of specifying something like 1,000,000 lines in the array to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a list of lists and append items to those lists. when you get to the end of the file cast the list of lists to a np.ndarray.
change

```
data = numpy.zeros((numcol,100000))
```

to

```
data = [[] for i in range(numcol)]
```

and change

```
data[i][ln]=(float(words[i]))
```

to

```
data[i].append(float(words[i]))
```

at the end of the code add

```
data = np.array(data)
```